# 3d files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, 3d, directx, direct3d, solidworks

I know this will be a difficult question, so I am not necessarily looking for a direct answer but maybe a tutorial or a point in the right direction.

What I am doing is programing a robot that will be controlled by a remote operator. We have a 3D rendering of the robot in SolidWorks. What I am looking to do is get the 3D file into VB (probably using DX9) and be able to manipulate it using code so that the remote operator will have a better idea of what the robot is doing. The operator will also have live video to look at, but that doesn't really matter for this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why even do this?  Since the robot has finite positions, just show an image of each position of the robot when the user has made the robot work.  A Robot load image, Robot unload image, Robot on fire and people spraying it with water and getting electrocuted image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a tough idea to implement. Well, for VB you are stuck with [MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX) 1.1(Comes with DirectX SDK) or [SlimDX](http://slimdx.mdxinfo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) (or other 3rd party Managed DirectX wrapper). The latest XNA (replacement for MDX 1.1/2.0b) is only available for C# coder. You can try some [workaround](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/XNA_in_VB.NET.aspx) but it's not recommended and you won't get much community support. These are the least you need to get your VB to display some 3d stuffs.

If you want to save some trouble, you could use ready made game engine to simplified you job. Try [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), and it's managed wrapper [MOgre](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/MOGRE). It was one of the candidate for my project. But I ended up with SlimDX due to Ogre not supporting video very well. But since video is not your requirement, you can really consider it. Most sample would be in C# also, so you need to convert to VB.Net to use. It won't be hard.

Here comes the harder part, you need to export your model exported from SolidWorks to DirectX Format (*.x). I did a quick search in google and only found a few paid tools to do that. You might need to spend a bit on that or spend more time looking for free converter tools.

That's about it. If you have more question, post again. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the real question is but what I suspect that you are trying to do is to be able to manipulate a SW model of a robot with some sort of a manual input.  Assuming that this is the correct question, there are two aspects that need to be dwelt with:

1)  The Solidworks module:  Once the model of the robot is working properly in SW, a program can be written in VB.Net that can manipulate the positional mates for each of the joints.  Also using VB, a window can be programmed with slide bars etc. that will allow the operator to be able to "remotely" control the robot.  Once this is done, there is a great opportunity to setup a table that could store the sequencial steps.  When completed, the VB program could be further developed to allow the robot to "cycle" through a sequence of moves.  If any obstacles are also added to the model, this would be a great tool for collission detection and training off line.

2)  If the question also includes the incorporation of a physical operator pendent there are a number of potential solutions for this.  It would be hoped that the robot software would provide a VB library for communicating and commanding the Robot programatically. If this is the case, then the VB code could then be developed with a "run" mode where the SW robot is controlled by the operator pendent, instead of the controls in the VB window, (as mentioned above).  This would then allow the opertor to work "offline" with a virtual robot.

Hope this helps.